# "quoted printable" or "7/8 bit" as transfer-encoding when send email

Tags: python, django, email

My app needs to send email to users. The backend is Django 1.4, which uses "7/8 bit" when send   email. Recently I found the delivery rate is low. One thing I've noticed is that Facebook uses `quoted-printable` to transfer email content, and also some other services.

Technically, which one is preferred when sending email contains unicode characters? Does this impact the spam score? I've heard base64 may cause intension from spam filters.